# looking for a code list for cil , as in what does 16, 17, 18 , 19 , 02 do

Tags: cil

I was wondering if there is a cil code list, I think 16 = false and 17 = true, but not 100% sure, also think -1 = 0 , but if anyone has a website to help with this that would be great.

```
16 = false 
17 = true ?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find a complete listing of all opcodes in Partition III of [ECMA-335](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-335.htm), but as for the specific instructions you listed:

```
02 (0x02) = ldarg.0
16 (0x10) = starg.s
17 (0x11) = ldloc.s
18 (0x12) = ldloca.s
19 (0x13) = stloc.s

0x16 = ldc.i4.0 // could be a 0 or false or '\0' ... the exact type depends on how it's used.
0x17 = ldc.i4.1 // could be a 1 or true or '\u0001' ... again, the exact type depends on how it's used.
0x18 = ldc.i4.2
0x19 = ldc.i4.3
```

Comment: From the OPs mentioning of 16 = false and 17 = true, i am pretty sure he just omitted the 0x and his numbers are actually hex.

Comment: Yeah, the thought occurred to me after posting and I was in the process of updating when you commented :)

Comment: ok i was thinking aob when i said cil.. but the cil website helps.. thanks